# Need to return a variable from a button click method and reuse it in another method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, windows-10

```
private async void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        StorageFile tempFile = await EncodeFileAsync();
      
        ......         
    }
```

```
private async void Save_Click(object sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ......

        }
```

I have tried using a global variable, but it will be empty since it awaits an async method. Awaiting it another time causes the encoding to happen once again.

Comment: Making your global variable as static may help.
Global variables are shared memory between all of your threads, tasks, etc. BUT for each object.

Comment: No, it doesn't work even if I make it static. It says I have to use it within an async method

Comment: Please set global variable after await line that could make sure variable assignment.

Comment: Could  you explain me how to do it? According to other questions in stackoverflow I cannot assign a global variable inside a method

Comment: Ok, I have upload code [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/TestBindOne/blob/master/TestBind/MainPage.xaml.cs#L91), please check.

Comment: Thanks Nico, that's very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the field after the async method has returned:

```
private StorageFile _tempFile;
private async void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var temp = await EncodeFileAsync();
    _tempFile = temp;
  
    ......         
}

private async void Save_Click(object sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (_tempFile != null)
        ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks man for the time you've spent to help me. Would like to upvote your answer, but my points don't allow me to do that :)

Comment: @MarcAnt01: I upvoted your question. Once you get a reputation of 15, you will be able to upvote helpful answers :)